# Nodejs URL: relative protocol URL string input

Tags: node.js, url

I am using the native nodejs `URL` module to parse URLs.

I initially solved the issue of no protocol `www.example.com`, through a regex function.

Now I am seeing protocol relative URLs `//example.com/path`.

Trying to avoid writing lots of checks and regex - is there a cleaner way to allow the module to accept more diverse input?